# Is CouchDB an example of Server Side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I looking at using Javascript server side and took a look at persevere/pintura but for a novice like me, I need more documentation and tutorials and CouchDB seems to have a lot of that but is it used as a server side js tool?

Kind Regards

Comment: Consider rethinking which of the answers is right one.

Comment: Nice to see the answer I consider the best checked :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes (seconding what @Pointy said above). The JavaScript in CouchDB does run server-side. :)

Beyond that, though, JavaScript in CouchDB can do far more than just map/reduce queries. It's also used for document validation, update handling (for processing XML POSTed to CouchDB for example), as well as HTML or other markup output from either a single JSON document (using _show) or from the results of a map/reduce query (using _list).

CouchDB does not, however, offer filesystem access or TCP/IP listeners as Node.js does. Right now, the JavaScript is focused on the "shipping and handling" for the database contents (things like validation, formatting, and querying).

If you're interested in looking into options for handling things that CouchDB doesn't do "internally" (image processing, sending e-mails, etc), you might checkout my reply about [CouchApp architecture options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164183/couchdb-choice-couchapp-without-server-side-or-couchdb-backend-with-xdomain-i/4176306#4176306).

CouchApp's are definitely a viable option for web apps. Coupling those with replication, it's hard to beat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your post " CouchApp architecture options." is also very helpful

Answer (score 2):

http://nodejs.org/ is a great example for server-side javascript. If you don't want to write your complete webapp on NodeJS you can trigger it via the `node` command.

Comment: I wouldnt mind writing my whole web app Nodejs. I didthe chat tutorial a few months back, but i didnt have any knowledge of how it worked under the hood, i am currently taking a look at.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB is a database with an interresting feature, it allows you to interact via a RestFull api making it ideally suited to access over the web, either in javascript or other client environments. If you are looking for a server-side javascript development environment, try [Servoy](http://www.servoy.com). It allows full featured server-side application development in javascript including easy database access to all major databases.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes.

Longer Answer:

There is a Javascript Engine shipped with CouchDB, which is [SpiderMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_%28JavaScript_engine%29)
(the very first engine, open source,  written by Brendan Eich, creator of javascript)

CouchDB's View function is JavaScript function running server side that acts as the Map half of a map/reduce operation to construct view.

Then there is client side javascript API, which can be used to communicate with the REST layer to fetch/update documents, which is also where jQuery is used by CouchDB.

### More on CouchDB's both server-side & client side javascript capability:

The default engine is capable of doing many features, while package availability is limited compared to Node.js. [Kan.so](http://kan.so/) can be considered "NPM for CouchDB, where some packages are server side.
For example, there are frameworks like [duality](http://kan.so/packages/details/duality) that try to make use of both server side & client side javascript capability to reuse code for rendering with couchDB.

### More on the engine:

(The selection of spider Monkey over v8 is because for couchDB's use case the map reduce is not v8 designed for. Also include packaging, multi-threading and also historical reason v8 did not exist that time when spiderMoney is chosen) see [the mailing list] and [tweet](https://twitter.com/CouchDB/status/14491793796)[2](http://kan.so/)

There is even project to port the whole CouchDB to Node.js (i.e. instead of Erlang), [Chesterfield](https://github.com/Vertexio/chesterfield/wiki/Design-Proposal)

I am glad if someone can add how Erlang talk with the javscript engine.
Thanks for everyone's answer, this is an important thing to make clear for people like me messing up couchDB with some Node.js packages

Answer (score 0):

No, `CouchDB` is a *document-oriented database* that can be queried and indexed in a MapReduce fashion using JavaScript. CouchDB also offers incremental replication with bi-directional conflict detection and resolution.

http://couchdb.apache.org/

`CommonJS` can be used for server side JavaScript, see here: http://www.commonjs.org/

`NodeJS` is another: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Thanks, i have learning javascript, ruby, html, css and have not bothered with the backend. Could you list the tools needed to use javascript from client-side to serverside? I assumed database and server side covered the same area with just a small overlap but i guess not. I am currently checking the links u game me.

Thanks

Comment: JS is also used for validation and creating lists and views in different formats. With Couchapp you can write complete webapps which are hosted on CouchDB and with the moving parts written in JS which runs hosted in the server.

Comment: This looks really cool and simple. The only worrying thing is the word "constraints" in their description. I will read through the documentation to check it out.

 "CouchApps are JavaScript and HTML5 applications served directly from CouchDB. If you can fit your application into those constraints, then you get CouchDB's scalability and flexibility "for free""

Comment: @SQLMenace "No" is not really the right answer, as CouchDB (via integration with SpiderMonkey) actually *does* allow for Javascript to be run in the server for things like map/reduce, as you say. It's on the server, and it's running Javascript, so how is that not "server-side Javascript"?  Generally the term means, "not in the web browser where everybody still expects it to be."

Comment: You are mixing up different concepts. CommonJS is a library standart. It has no use by itself. CouchDB implements CommonJS. [Proof link](http://www.commonjs.org/impl) So you are contradicting yourself.